# jquery find link by rel

Tags: jquery

i have some links in my page

```
< a class="Qlink" rel="20;5" href="javascript:void(0);">5</a>
< a class="Qlink" rel="21;6" href="javascript:void(0);">6</a>
< a class="Qlink" rel="22;7" href="javascript:void(0);">7</a>
```

i do some ajax call and get the first number on the rel attribute(exp. 20)

how do i can change the class of link (the first in my exp.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$("a[rel^='20;']").addClass('foo');
```

See also: [attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue)

Answer (score 3):

A combination of Kobi and Soufiane's answers will do what the OP is asking:

```
$("a[rel^=20]").attr('class', 'your_new_class');
```

He asked to change the class, after all.

Comment: Tnx, i needed the attributeStartsWith.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to change the class attribute of your links:

```
$('a.Qlink').attr('class','your_new_class');
```

**Edit:**
Based on the other answers, this one is better :

```
$('a[rel^=20]').attr('class','your_new_class');
```